# What are the differences between network slicing and VLANs?

Tags: vlan

[According to Ericsson](https://cloudblog.ericsson.com/digital-services/what-is-network-slicing), network slicing is defined as follows:

> Network slicing enables you to build multiple logical networks—network slices—on top of a common shared physical infrastructure. These network slices, typically one for each kind of service, are completely separated and independents to the extent that if something goes wrong in one slice it will not affect the other slices. This separation and independence also enable you to add new slices without impacting the rest of the network.

As I understand it, building logical networks for different purposes on top of a physical one is exactly what VLANs are for. Therefore, is network slicing just a new term for the same thing, or is there something I didn't catch ?

Comment: Welcome Nakrule.  My understanding is that it's a 5G wireless facility, approximately the purposes of QoS+VLAN.  IEEE paper https://sdn.ieee.org/newsletter/january-2018/a-network-service-provider-perspective-on-network-slicing and GSMA paper https://www.gsma.com/futurenetworks/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/GSMA-An-Introduction-to-Network-Slicing.pdf

Comment: @jonathanjo Thank for your inputs, but theses two documents only describe the benefits of logical networks without mentioning how they are technically implemented. As this link points out (https://www.grandmetric.com/2016/07/05/5g-norma-vs-ip-networks-techniques-slicing/), slicing can be made with either VLAN or VRP, so as it is old technologies, why are people so enthusiast about it ?

Comment: Indeed, it does seem to be marketing driven.  I do hope a 5G expert comes in with an answer.